# Spring Webflux Async PostgreSQL Publisher Stops After First Result

Tags: spring, postgresql, websocket, rx-java, spring-webflux

I am trying to replace a PostgreSQL database poller with the reactive asynchronous [postgres-async-driver](https://github.com/alaisi/postgres-async-driver) and stream newly inserted rows to a Spring 5 Webflux Reactive websocket client like [Josh Long](https://stackoverflow.com/users/607357/josh-long)'s awesome example demoed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763126/reactive-websockets-with-spring-5-how-to-get-initial-message) and based on [Sébastien Deleuze's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1092077/s%C3%A9bastien-deleuze) [spring-reactive-playground](https://github.com/joshlong/spring-reactive-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/playground/postgres/PostgresPersonRepository.java).

My `Publisher` obtains the first `row`, but then does not return subsequent rows.
Is the problem with my `Observable`, my `Publisher`, or with how I am using the postgres-async-driver `Db`?

```
public Observable<WebSocketMessage> getObservableWSM(WebSocketSession session){
    return
        // com.github.pgasync.Db
        db.queryRows(sql)
        // ~RowMapper method
        .map(row -> mapRowToDto(row))
        // serialize dto to String for websocket
        .map(dto -> { return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dto); })
        // finally, write to websocket session 
        .map(str -> { return session.textMessage((String) str);
        });
}
```

Then, I wire the `Observable` into my `WebSocketHandler` using a `RxReactiveStream.toPublisher` converter:

```
@Bean
WebSocketHandler dbWebSocketHandler() {
    return session -> {
        Observable<WebSocketMessage> o = getObservableWSM(session);
        return session.send(Flux.from(RxReactiveStreams.toPublisher(o)));
    };
}
```

That will grab the first `row` from my `sql` statement, but no additional rows. How do I continue to stream additional rows?

Ideally, I think I want the PostgreSQL equivalent of a MongoDB [Tailable cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47456820/237225).

Comment: Hi Zabkar, `postgres-async-driver` is not really reactive. Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402550/webflux-postgresql/48402788#48402788). Tailable cursor works on **capped collections** wich is a specificity of MongoDB.

Comment: @montassar The linked answer also sidesteps Postgres. There's already a solution out there for Redis and MongoDB; I'm looking for a Postgres solution.

Comment: Agree. I attended the Spring Boot 2.0 webinar by Phil Webb and we asked the question. The response was clearly: Not yet. I can notice that you use Rx-Java but I saw a **Reactor** project feature wich is `Scheduler` susceptible to help you. Please see Grygoriy Gonchar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299455/spring-webflux-and-reading-from-database). Personnally, I see that as a workAround, but if you don't want to wait... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a [Postgres Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-trigger.html) that fires on `INSERT`s to my table based on 
[this example](https://gist.github.com/fritzy/5db6221bebe53eda4c2d):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_update_notify() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  id bigint;
BEGIN
  IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
    id = NEW.id;
  ELSE
    id = OLD.id;
  END IF;
  PERFORM pg_notify('my_trigger_name', json_build_object('table', TG_TABLE_NAME, 'id', id, 'type', TG_OP)::text);
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then I subscribed to that Postgres Trigger using [reactive-pg-client](https://reactiverse.io/reactive-pg-client/guide/java/).
Here is the code from their Pub/Sub example:

```
@Bean
PgPool subscribedNotificationHandler() {
    PgPool client = pgPool();
    client.getConnection(asyncResult -> {
        if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
            PgConnection connection = asyncResult.result();
            connection.notificationHandler(notification -> {
                notification.getPayload();
                // do things with payload
            });
            connection.query("LISTEN my_trigger_name", ar -> {
                log.info("Subscribed to channel");
            });
        }
    });
    return client;
}
```